# Deriving a test for a given statistics

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, statistical-inference, symmetry, hypothesis-testing

Let $X$ be a random variable following a symmetric distribution with variance 1.

Let $m$ be the median.

Now, take a random sample of size $n$ and define $Z:= \sqrt{n} \overline{X}$.

We wish to test the following hypotheses:
\begin{align*} H_0 : m &= 0 \\
H_1 : m &< 0
\end{align*}

Determine a test based on $Z$ with significance level $0.05$.

I don't know how to use the facts that we have been given to help me, but I do know that I'm trying to find a critical region $(-\infty, c)$ such that $\mathbb{P}(Z \leq c) = 0.05$.

Can anyone help me?

:)

Comment: Do you know Chebyshev's inequality?

Comment: Yes I can see how that would help us use the variance, but I don't understand why it helps us because it only provides an upper bound?